# GCC: mtune vs march vs mcpu

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to make some optimized builds on several ARM SBCs, where each build will have compatibility only on the target platform I'm building on.

I've heard that -march is preferable here over -mtune as it will break backwards compatibility with other cpus in the architecture family by generating instructions that are only compatible with the host cpu. -mtune on the other hand will keep this compatibility.

However, I've read that -mcpu is possibly the best flag to set instead of -march or -mtune as -mcpu is specific to the very processor, not just the more common architecture specified  by -marm (a difference of something like -mcpu=cortex-a8 over -march=armv7-a).

Now the tricky thing is I'm also reading that -mcpu is deprecated and its functionality is taken over by -mtune, which conflicts with my previous comments regarding the use of -mtune being undesirable when compared to -march and -marm being undesirable when compared to -mcpu.

Essentially, which flag will give me the best performance for the host machine when I don't care to maintain compatibility with other cpus at all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`-mcpu` unfortunately has different semantics for different targets. It's [deprecated for x86](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/957a727b7cb23a41884abbd24fdeaeeb5e6db306/gcc/doc/invoke.texi#L24603) (being a synonym for `-mtune`) but not for ARM, where it's [a sum of `-march` and `-mtune`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/doc/invoke.texi#L13988).

So to answer your question - on ARM, always use `-mcpu` for best performance, unless you care for backwards compatibility.