# gcc cpu and fpu config flag for Atmel AT91SAM9G45?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am building `arm-eabi-gcc` with gcc 6.3.0 source, to target the Atmel AT91SAM9G45 processor.

What should I use for the `cpu` / `arch` / `tune` flags when configuring the gcc build?

Using `--with-arch=armv9` returns `Unknown arch used`. It appears to accept `--with-cpu=armv9`, and not passing an `arch` flag, but I'm not sure if this is right for this particular CPU. It also accepts `--with-cpu=arm9` and I'm not sure what the difference between the two is, or if either is right for my CPU.

Also, what should I use for the `--with-fpu` option? My software will not be using any floating point operations so I am using `--with-float=hard`, but I don't know what to do for the fpu option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I use for the cpu / arch / tune flags when configuring the gcc build?

As can be seen from [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-6438-32-bit-ARM926-Embedded-Microprocessor-SAM9G45_Datasheet.pdf), AT91SAM9G45 includes an old ARM926EJ-S core. It's supported by GCC via `arm926ej-s` name (search for supported `-mtune` values [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)). So I'd suggest to use `--with-cpu=arm926ej-s`.

As for distinction between `--with-tune`, `--with-arch` and `--with-cpu`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718572/gcc-mtune-vs-march-vs-mcpu/42722790#42722790), TLDR is that `--with-cpu` is preferred).

> Using --with-arch=armv9 returns Unknown arch used.

Don't confuse ARM9 and ARMv9 - they are totally different things.

> Also, what should I use for the --with-fpu option?

I don't think ARM9 supports FP in hardware so you should use `--with-float=soft`.